# can't communicate with spawn process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

hi i'm working on an electron app
form the app i wise to control several external command line applications, for example plink,
i i'm using windows
i trying to use spwan to great a cmd process :

```js
const p = spawn('cmd', ['\\c'] ) // c or K both yield the same result

p.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8')

p.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
})

p.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
})

p.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
})
```

after ruining, i'm getting the fallowing output

> stdout: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
> Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\electron>

after that i'm running a simple command

```js
p.stdin.write('hostname\n')
```

but no response is typed back into the console...

Comment: If it's windows, try `\r\n`?

Comment: same result .....